# Transform Mousemove like this example

Tags: jquery, transform, mousemove, mouseleave

Well, after 1 day of research, I'm not able to do what I want ^^

I want this : http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-promo/

Scroll a little bit and you will find 4 pictures, when you are hovering one of them, it's scaled up and follow smoothly your pointer. When you get off the picture, it's go back to the first state.

My question is How to do that?

I tried this :

```
$('.img-anim').mousemove(function(e){
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;

        traX = (e.pageX * -1 / 20);
        traY = (e.pageY * -1 / 20);
        console.log(traX);
        $(".img-anim").css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + traX + 'px,' + traY + 'px, 0) scale(1.2)',
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(' + traX + 'px,' + traY + 'px, 0) scale(1.2)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + traX + 'px,' + traY + 'px, 0) scale(1.2)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(' + traX + 'px,' + traY + 'px, 0) scale(1.2)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(' + traX + 'px,' + traY + 'px, 0) scale(1.2)'
        });
      });
```

But it doesn't work because my pictures are not in full screen, this is just 4 pictures in the wild of my code. Also, when you are hovering one of them, the translation is done on all of them and when you leave the hover, the picture stays at the last state, it doesn't go back as seen the first time.

So, if someone hears me, I would be very grateful to receive some help!

Best regards

Comment: Hey dude, can you provide a fiddle or something with your full code ?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/jx7rkqcz/4/ 
It's strange because on the fiddle, the pictures don't follow the pointer but I don't know why?